# Methods for Analyzing Critical Points when the Second Derivative Test Fails

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I know that when the second partial derivative test comes out inconclusive, you can use geometry and observation to sort of classify the critical points. How would one use analytical methods, such as higher order partial derivatives or total derivatives, to analyze the critical and classify them accordingly?

Comment: +1 Very interesting question.

Comment: you should be able to interpret the 2nd derivative test as being implied by writing your function as a taylor polynomial, with the 1st derivative = 0, and the 2nd degree term being in the Lagrange Form of a remainder... if the Hessian is e.g. PSD, then consider writing the Taylor Polynomial instead with the 3rd degree term in the Lagrange Form of remainder and so on.  Computationally anything beyond the quadratic... will be hard to work with likely becoming questions of algebraic geometry.

Comment: @user8675309 Do you know of any books or notes that go into detail about the method you expressed?

Comment: Kind of --  I am pretty sure this is discussed in a coordinate free way (and I think later with coordinates) in Koerner's *A Companion to Analysis*.  I also have a feeling it may be in Hubbard and Hubbards multivariate calc book.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks!